# peerDependencies and npm install

Tags: angularjs, npm, seed

I would like to configure my own Angular seed which will be include Angular and Angular material. Problem is when I want run npm install from `package.json` which have :

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "angular": "@>=1.3 <1.6",
    "angular-animate": "^@>=1.3 <1.6",
    "angular-aria": "@>=1.3 <1.6",
    "angular-messages": "@>=1.3 <1.6"
},
"dependencies": {
},
```

I get an error from console like pm WARN material-start@0.0.4 requires a peer of angular@@>=1.3 <1.6 but none was installed.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand what `peerDependencies` mean.

Peer dependances aren't installed by `npm` itself. Npm just fires an error when you try to install this packgaje to environment which doesn't satisfy it's peerDependances.
I recommend you to use `dependances` in your `package.json` for `angular` and other packgajes required by `material`. So npm could install them automatically, before `material` installation.

Comment: So I must specify version in Depedencies and then my packages will be installed if I choose suitable version?